# Custom font is not working in Subscription PDF output SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am building a report in SSRS with One time Subscription. It would run periodically and export the output in PDF format. I am using Monotype Corsiva font for some text so that did set up the font as the default font in the report.

I can see the font in both Visual Studio Preview, Web service of Report server. But when I run subscription, it is not working. Some other font is displaying.

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Check this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/008bdfcb-1c2f-4245-a30b-6e239465d443/font-rendering-issues-in-export-to-pdfssrs?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: @niktrs I'm unable to get what is in this link.

Answer (score 0):

delete the installed .ttf file in c->windows->fonts.. Right click on downloaded .ttf file ..select install for all users..restart the system
[image click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBo8O.png)